# ODBC from Win10 32bit client only connects using IP address, but not using hostname

Tags: sql-server-2016, odbc, windows-10

I'm experiencing a pretty strange problem.

We're using a MS SQL based quality assurance software. The database is hosted on a MS SQL 2016 Std. server running on a Windows Server 2012 R2 VM.

Our clients are a mix of mostly 64bit Windows 7 and Windows 10 clients.

In order to connect a client to the SQL server we have to create an ODBC connection using the odbcad32.exe situated at c:\windows\syswow64\ on 64bit clients or under c:\windows\system32 on 32bit machines.

Now, one of those Windows 10 32bit clients straight out refuses to connect to the SQL server using the hostname.
When adding the connection, I'm using the "SQL Server" ODBC driver version 10.00.17763.01, the same driver which works without any problems on 64bit Windows 10 clients.

I can select the SQL server instance and enter the appropriate SQL user name and passwords.
The connection however times out with the following, unfortunately German error message:

[image]

Manually entering the ip address of the SQL server allows me to connect to the SQL server instance without any problems.
Since the license of the software is linked to the hostname of the SQL server which hosts the database, I can't login afterwards...I need to connect to the database using the hostname and not the ip address.

Unfortunately, this is the only 32bit Windows 10 client in our environment, so I can't say if there is something wrong with this particular machine.

Anybody ever stumbled across a similar problem? Is there perhaps a dedicated ODBC SQL server driver for 32bit Windows 10?

Thanks in advance,

Dominik

Comment: Try using the SQL Native Client driver instead. 

If that does not work, does your SQL server have more then one SQL instance on it?

Comment: Try to ping the name of the sql server from the 32 bit computer to make sure it can be resolved. If not, you have to look into network setting. what is different with this computer compared to other computers

Comment: If this is the only 23 bits machine, why don't upgrade it?

Comment: I tried the SQL Native Client driver version 11, the issue remained the same, however. Name resolution seems fine, I can ping the hostname and the FQDN without problems. I can also telnet to the 1433 tcp port of the SQL instance without any issues...so I don't think that there's a client side networking issue. I'll probably simply publish the application in question as a Remote App on our Remote Desktop server and call it a day...then I'll reinstall the machine with Win10 64bit ASAP.